# What is "and therefore profits"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have read an article called "Stocks have shrugged off the banking turmoil. Haven’t they?" in The Economist newspaper, but I find it hard to understand the meaning of a sentence.
The sentence is

> **A credit crunch will crimp economic growth and therefore profits.**

Context of the sentence:

> Bank failures are usually bad for business. A sickly banking system
> will lend less and at higher interest rates to companies in need of
> capital. **A credit crunch will crimp economic growth and therefore
> profits**. On occasion, a bad bank can blow up the financial system,
> causing a cascade of pain. Investors know this. They have dumped
> stocks when banks have failed before.

Which option below correctly represents the meaning of the aforementioned sentence?

1. The credit crunch will crimp economic growth, as a result, the credit crunch will crimp profits.
2. The credit crunch will crimp economic growth, for that reason, the credit crunch will bring profits.

Comment: A credit crunch will crimp economic growth, and therefore (it will crimp) profits. You could google _ellipsis_ to read more about such constructions.

Comment: Aren't "economic growth" and "profits" just both objects of "crimp"? Why does it need a more complex explanation?

Comment: @StuartF I think you're right there.

Comment: To answer the question, _and therefore profits_ is a conjoined clause that's been reduced to just a noun phrase and a couple conjunctions by the rule of Conjunction Reduction. What it's reduced from is the clause _and therefore **a credit crunch will crimp** profits_, with all of the stuff repeated from the first clause deleted. Conjunction reduction applies to any conjoined constituent, from noun phrases to clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profit is a noun. The context forces this.

If it were a verb, its subject would be "A credit crunch" and the sentence would be economic nonsense. Hence 2. is nonsense.